# How to Parse Command Line Arguments in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to make a C# application that takes command line arguments (username and password) and declares them both as variables, so I would give arguments Bob and 12345, and it would save Bob as variable: Username, and 12345 as variable: Password.  How would I do this?

Comment: Total incorrect flag as duplicate @Kevin, the question is way simpler

Comment: You're right.  My bad.

Comment: No, that's about options that don't change each run. Still not the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can do this using [Command Line Arguments](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288457%28v=vs.71%29.aspx).

Example:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       //The arguments are 0 and 1, for the first and second args.
       var username = args[0];
       var password = args[1];
   }
```

Comment: Oh, thank you, I thought it would be much harder!

Comment: Glad to help. MSDN often has answers.

Comment: @ZacHeimgartner, most modern (and some old) languages can do this btw.